# setInterval в JavaScript: новый вызов по окончании предыдущего

Tags: javascript

```
 setInterval(receiveComent, 1000)
```

При этой строчке функция receiveComent, будет вызываться каждую секунду, как сделать, чтобы вызывалась только тогда, когда receiveComent полностью завершит свою работу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте setTimeout вместо setInterval:

```
setTimeout(doit, 1000);
function doit() {
    // TODO: ...
    setTimeout(doit, 1000);
}
```

И заново заряжайте таймер в конце кода.